# limit servlet cpu usage in tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Some of my servlets will involve heavy procession and time-consuming. And other servlets are simple. If the heavy servlet calls are very high in number, the simple servlets cannot be used. so, I want to limit the heavy servlets that it can use only up to 50% of the total CPU. Is it possible? if so, please explain how/where to proceed in tomcat.

Comment: instead try to optimize your code

Answer (score 0):

Capsulate the code away from the rest of the application as war

**then**

create a secound instance of Tomcat and `configure via the operating system the priority`.

[Ubuntu (Linux) system priority](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48708/change-niceness-priority-of-a-running-process)

**or**

try to set `threadPriority` into  the `Executor (thread pool) in Tomcat`